# Importing package "imutil" works in PyCharm and python terminal but not windows terminal

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm

In Pycharm (runs on Python 3.7), I am doing this Computer Visions tutorial which requires the package imutils. The interesting thing is that if I run this file named "neural_style_transfer", it works fine. But according to the tutorial we must run the following in the windows terminal

```
neural_style_transfer.py --image images/giraffe.jpg \
--model models/eccv16/the_wave.t7
```

When I run that, it says "no module name imutils".

Some more background: For some reason, when I use the IDE spyder, there is also no module named imutils. But I think it is because my spyder is still in python 3.6. 
My imutils is definitely located in the python 3.7 packages stuff, I can find it at:

```
C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\imutils
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution! Anyways, you have to call:

**py -m pip install imutils** in your terminal

The logical explanation I found is this: I have 3 versions of pythons on my computer: 2.7, 3.6, 3.7. I have 3.6 because tensorflow doesn't support python 3.7 yet. But if you only call pip install imutils, it only downloads imutils to your python 3.7 site packages, which is not shared across all the python versions and is not the version I use when I do deeplearning. Therefore, to download imutils to python 3.6 (the version I use), use **py -m pip install imutils**.

There's still many potholes in my conjecture though: for example, py-m pip install sounds like it doesn't specify downloading to 3.6, so why does it download to 3.6? And, for most of the time, I thought I was working on python 3.7, which should had imutils installed, but maybe I was working on 3.6 instead of 3.7.